# How to make this Swap Function only work when requirement is fullfilled

Tags: erc-20, uniswap, require

Hi I'm new in contract developing. The following snippet includes a swap funtion for a swap on uniswap. This swap should only work if the requirement `require((balanceOf(to) + amountToSwap) <= _maxWlt, "Wallet size / Purchase too big.");` is fullfilled. But it also passes if this is not the case. Can anyone tell me where the problem is.

```
   uint256 _maxWlt;
    _maxWlt = (totalSupply() * 3) / 100;
    
    // Swap tokens for another ERC20 token using Uniswap
    function swapTokensForToken(
        address tokenOut,
        uint256 amountIn,
        uint256 amountOutMin,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external ensure(deadline) nonReentrant {
    
        require(tokenOut != address(0), "Invalid token address");
        require(tokenOut != address(this), "Cannot swap to the same token");
        require(amountIn > 0, "Amount must be greater than 0");
    
    
        // Calculate the amount to swap after deducting fees
        uint256 amountToSwap = _handleFeesAndCalculateAmount(amountIn);
        require((balanceOf(to) + amountToSwap) <= _maxWlt, "Wallet size / Purchase too big.");
        
        // Transfer tokens from the sender to this contract
        _transfer(msg.sender, address(this), amountIn);
    
    
        // Approve the Uniswap router to spend tokens
        _approve(address(this), UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER, amountToSwap);
    
        // Prepare the token path for the swap
        address[] memory path;
        if (tokenOut == weth) {
            path = new address[](2);
            path[0] = address(this);
            path[1] = weth; // Use the updated weth address
        } else {
            path = new address[](3);
            path[0] = address(this);
            path[1] = weth; // Use the updated weth address
            path[2] = tokenOut;
        }
    
        // Perform the swap on Uniswap
        uniswapRouter.swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            amountToSwap,
            amountOutMin,
            path,
            to,
            block.timestamp
        );
    }
```